# three PHP value pass to jQuery

Tags: php

I would just like to ask if passing of three values from PHP to jQuery would be possible?

you see i have this three drop downs: one for the month, one for the year and one for the user. you can choose to view the data of the user on the chosen month and year. all i have right now is this.

This is the drop down for the month, year and user:

```
$years = array(10=>'Select year','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022','2023','2024','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030');
$year_count= count($years);
$year = $year_count +9;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $("#months").change(function(event)
   {
      var m=$(this).val();
      if(m!='00' || m!='NULL')
      {
         $("#memcount").load('crd_reports/month.php', {"m":m, "y": $("#years").val(), "user":$("#user").(val)});
         $("#top10").load('crd_reports/top10_monthly.php', {"m":m, "y": $("#years").val()});
      }
  });

  $("#years").change(function(event)
   {
      var y=$(this).val();
      if(y!='10' || y!='NULL')
      {
         $("#memcount").load('crd_reports/month.php', {"y":y, "user":$("#user").val(), "m": $("#months").val()});
         $("#top10").load('crd_reports/top10_monthly.php', {"y":y, "m": $("#months").val()});
      }
   });

    $("#user").change(function(event)
    {
       var user=$(this).val();
       if(user!='00' || user!='NULL')
       {
          $("#memcount").load('crd_reports/month.php', {"user":user, "m"m, "y:"y, "user": $("#user").val()});
       }
    });
});
</script>   

<div align="left">
Month:  <select id="months">
        <option>Select month</option>
        <option value='01'>Jan</option>
        <option value='02'>Feb</option>
        <option value='03'>Mar</option>
        <option value='04'>Apr</option>
        <option value='05'>May</option>
        <option value='06'>June</option>
        <option value='07'>July</option>
        <option value='08'>Aug</option>
        <option value='09'>Sept</option>
        <option value='10'>Oct</option>
        <option value='11'>Nov</option>
        <option value='12'>Dec</option>
    </select>

Year: <select id="years">
<?php
for($yr=10; $yr<=$year; $yr++)
{
    echo "<option value='".$yr."'>".$years[$yr]."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo "Select CRD User: <select id='user'>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE admin_level LIKE 'CRD'");
 while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
     echo "<option value='".$fetch['id']."'>".$fetch['username']."</option>";
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div id ="memcount"><?php include('curr_month2.php')?></div>       <!--display graph-->
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div id="top10"><?php include('curr_top10m.php')?></div>       <!--display graph for top 10-->
```

This is the code for the php where the value of month, year and user were passed:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['m']) && isset($_POST['y']) && isset($_POST['user'])) 
{
$m = $_POST['m'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
include '../../include/config.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE admin_level LIKE 'CRD' ORDER BY id";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
?>

<div id='memcount' style='width: 680px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

<?php
$limit = 5;0
$c=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name[$c] = $row['first_name'];
    $id[$c]= $row['id'];
    $c++;
}

for($i=0; $i< $c; $i++)
    {
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(crdid) AS count_id, crdid, id, timestamp FROM crd_project 
                                 WHERE crdid='$user' 
                                     AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                     AND week_num!='NULL'");
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
        {
            $total[] = (int)$fetch['count_id'];
        }


    //week1
        $week_1_id = mysql_query("SELECT crdid,count(crdid) AS week_1total, week_num FROM crd_project
                                    WHERE crdid!='NULL' 
                                       AND crdid='$user' 
                                       AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                       AND week_num LIKE '1' 
                                       AND week_num!='NULL'");
         while($week_1_num= mysql_fetch_array($week_1_id))
         {
            $week_1_tot[] = (int)$week_1_num['week_1total']; 
         }

    //week2
        $week_2_id = mysql_query("SELECT crdid,count(crdid) AS week_2total, week_num  FROM crd_project 
                                    WHERE crdid!='NULL' 
                                        AND crdid='$user' 
                                        AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                        AND week_num LIKE '2' 
                                        AND week_num!='NULL'");
         while($week_2_num= mysql_fetch_array($week_2_id))
         {
            $week_2_tot[] = (int)$week_2_num['week_2total']; 
         }

    //week3
        $week_3_id = mysql_query("SELECT crdid,count(crdid) AS week_3total, week_num  FROM crd_project 
                                    WHERE crdid!='NULL' 
                                        AND crdid='$user'
                                        AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                        AND week_num LIKE '3'
                                        AND week_num!='NULL'");
        while($week_3_num= mysql_fetch_array($week_3_id))
        {
            $week_3_tot[] = (int)$week_3_num['week_3total']; 
        }

    //week4
        $week_4_id = mysql_query("SELECT crdid,count(crdid) AS week_4total, week_num  FROM crd_project 
                                    WHERE crdid!='NULL'
                                        AND crdid='$user' 
                                        AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                        AND week_num LIKE '4' 
                                        AND week_num!='NULL'");
         while($week_4_num= mysql_fetch_array($week_4_id))
         {
            $week_4_tot[] = (int)$week_4_num['week_4total']; 
         }


    //week5
         $week_5_id = mysql_query("SELECT crdid,count(crdid) AS week_5total, week_num  FROM crd_project 
                                     WHERE crdid!='NULL' 
                                        AND crdid='$user' 
                                        AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                        AND week_num LIKE '5' 
                                        AND week_num!='NULL'");
        while($week_5_num= mysql_fetch_array($week_5_id))
        {
                $week_5_tot[] = (int)$week_5_num['week_5total']; 
        }

    //week6 
         $week_6_id = mysql_query("SELECT crdid,count(crdid) AS week_6total, week_num  FROM crd_project
                                      WHERE crdid!='NULL' 
                                        AND crdid='$user' 
                                        AND timestamp LIKE '%/$m/$y%' 
                                        AND week_num LIKE '6' AND week_num!='NULL'");
         while($week_6_num= mysql_fetch_array($week_6_id))
        {
            $week_6_tot[] = (int)$week_6_num['week_6total']; 
        }
}       
$fname = json_encode($name);
$total = json_encode($total);
$number = json_encode($c);
$week_1_total = json_encode($week_1_tot);
$week_2_total = json_encode($week_2_tot);
$week_3_total = json_encode($week_3_tot);
$week_4_total = json_encode($week_4_tot);
$week_5_total = json_encode($week_5_tot);
$week_6_total = json_encode($week_6_tot);

echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm kind of lazy and that is a lot of code.  The answer is you can integrate php and javascript pretty easily, but too much code to show you.

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify what you are getting at. There is an existing passing from PHP to jQuery already when you called `.load()`. What do you want to do?

Comment: I added the jQuery for the passing of user then it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass value from PHP to jquery.

```
You can place the value in hidden field  and get it from that field in js, like
<input type="hidden" id="someFld" value="value_from_php">
//get the value
$("#someFld").val();

//or you can directly use the php value into js, like
var yourJsVariable = '<?php echo $yourPHPValue; ?>';
```

Hope it helps